# Modifying UINavigation controller programatically in Xcode5

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, xcode5

I have a programmatically generated `UINavigationController` applied to each of my `ViewControllers` but this `UINavigationController` is blank.  I need to add some text, an image (if possible) and two buttons.

I have managed to do something similar with a very basic app that only has one ViewController and `UINavigationController` created in the normal manner but do not know what to do in regards to a programmatically generated one.

I am using storyboards in `XCode5/iOS7`.

Here is the code that generates the `UINavigationController` and launches the first `ViewController`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    MainViewController* mainVC = [mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    UINavigationController *navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainVC];

    [self.window setRootViewController:navVC];

    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I have tried things that I thought would be obvious like:

```
navVC.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

To change the colour or:

```
[navVC setTitle:@"Test title"];
```

But nothing changes, the only way I could get the title to change was to change the title of  mainVC

```
[mainVC setTitle:@"Test title"];
```

Changing the title in the `MainViewController.m` file itself does nothing.

So how do I modify the `UINavigationController` (navVC)?

Thanks,

Comment: If you're using storyboards, why don't you put the navigation controller on the storyboard instead of trying to nest the contents of the storyboard into a programmatically created nav controller?  There may be a good reason, but I can't imagine one...

Comment: I needed the NavigationController to simply be a bar at the top of each VC that had a static title and buttons, e.i. the exact same layout on every page rather than an actual Navigation between the VCs, if that makes sense.  The only way I could think to do that was to programmatically generate the NC and apply the same 'instance' to each VC.  It seems Luca has given the answer to this one now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set an image to your navigation bar in this way:

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = navVC.navigationBar;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourNavBarImg.png"];
[navBar setBackgroundImage:image];
```

and this to change the nav bar tint color:

```
[navVC.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
[navVC.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

about buttons (UIBarButtonItem) into nav bar:

```
// where "self" is your current viewcontroller
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:button1,button2, nil];
```

Comment: Perfect, this does exactly what I need I clearly wasn't targeting the navigationBar.  Thanks.